# SonarQube fails to display Issues due to TypeError

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube keeps throwing the following error when navigating to the issues page. All other pages load normally.

Running Version 7.1 (build 11001), upgraded from 6.7.1 LTS recently.

`TypeError
columnNumber: 63588
fileName: "https://sonarurl.com/js/main.e04508c4.js"
lineNumber: 1
message: "e is undefined"
stack: "r@https://sonarurl.com/js/main.e04508c4.js:1:63588\ni@https://sonarurl.com/js/main.e04508c4.js:1:61493\nbeginWork@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:47974\nr@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:52441\ni@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:52762\nu@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:52998\nE@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:56521\nw@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:56258\nv@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:55390\nd@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:54794\nenqueueSetState@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:54:45232\nv.prototype.setState@https://sonarurl.com/js/vendors~main.57ecd91f.chunk.js:70:1118\n[1185]/Yt</t.prototype.fetchFirstIssues/<@https://sonarurl.com/js/268.c0ee6e84.chunk.js:1:92995\n"`

Comment: Could you please add more information : version of SonarQube, have you recently migrated from a previous version, etc.

Comment: Hi. Updated question with version information. thanks.

Comment: Which browser are you using?